# wp_mail is not working in custom wordpress plugin file

Tags: php, wordpress

i changed my mail() to wp_mail() after that it is not shoting emails here is my code.

```
$subject='test mail';

$body = '<table><tr>test</tr></table>';

add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );

$mail = wp_mail("test@mail.com","$subject", "$body");

remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );

function set_html_content_type() 
{
  return 'text/html';
}
```

i have also tested by below code and it is printing 'no'.

```
if($mail)
{
 echo "done";
}
else
{
 echo "no";
}
```

Comment: It's working fine here

Comment: @BhumiShah is there any file or anything else which i have to call or do?

Comment: no, your code is working fine in my wordpress.

Comment: @BhumiShah smtp is needed or not?